# Store img src in php variable

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to take an image from src of img tag and store it in a PHP variable.

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="crop"/>
```

somehow extract src and store in $image of php
Assume I am not aware of src value before hand.
Thanks please help.

Comment: Add your code that you have tried.

Comment: this is the code I just want to exract the src value and store it in a php variable. @Jalpa

Comment: Explain the situation - do you take above the code form outside source or something? Where is it relative to your php code?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed you have just one image ?

Comment: I am taking image from my db and using jcrop to crop that image and then displaying it in img tag but I don't know how to store it in my mysql db so I want to take src of img tag and that will do my work. @MichałSkrzypek

Comment: am taking image from my db and using jcrop to crop that image and then displaying it in img tag but I don't know how to store it in my mysql db so I want to take src of img tag and that will do my work.  @Jalpa

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not very clear ....
If after cropping your image you want to get src and store it in DB or whatever 
you can simply got this with jQuery
for example

```
<img src='abc.png' class='myimg'>

<input type='hidden' class='myimg_name_holder'>
```

then with jQuery

$(".myimg_name_holder").val($(".myimg").attr('src'));

Now you have your image name in a hidden input field now you can do whatever you want whether save in db or whatever....